# Expanded UITABLEVIEW with buttons like in TAPBOTS / PASTEBOT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am struggling with creating an expanded cell similiar to the one in PASTEBOT APP (with utility buttons). 
I've tried various approaches and none seems to give me smooth table scroll ( without jerking ) - it is really slow on Iphone 3G. What i've tried is modyfing the heightForRowAtIndexPath method and forcing a smooth refresh using the UITableView's beginUpdates/endUpdates methods. Problem with this approach is the fact it requires providing the expanded content for each cell and simply hiding it (using clipping) for the unexpanded cells. This seems unefficient. Another thing i've tried is inserting a new cell at the selectedIndex. Now there's a problem with refreshing the other cells (previously added/expanded). Using a combination of datasource's deleteElementAtIndex and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths gives an unsatisfactory result (unsmooth, hectic animations). Anyone familiar with a way to make an expand like in PASTEBOT ?  [Take a look at this picture!](http://www.coolastenbears.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/paste-bot-iphone-03.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more thing. EXPAND itself is not a problem - it works great. The biggest issue I have is very slow scrolling when I add buttons inside expanded cell.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm stuck on implementing that very same feature.